# Adding where condition with index make query slower(use filesort and temporary)

Tags: mysql-5.7

I'm trying to implement soft-delete so I added `deleted_at` (datetime) column to users table.
Also there is a query i need to run:

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count_all,
    `users`.`category_id` AS users_category_id
FROM
    `users`
GROUP BY `users`.`category_id`;



type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'index', 'index_users_on_category_id', 'index_users_on_category_id', '5', NULL, '840926', '100.00', 'Using index'
```

which was running just fine until i added  WHERE clause

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count_all,
    `users`.`category_id` AS users_category_id
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
GROUP BY `users`.`category_id`;

type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'ref', 'index_users_on_category_id,index_users_on_deleted_at', 'index_users_on_deleted_at', '6', 'const', '420463', '100.00', 'Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort'
```

Of course it becomes slower, i can't find information

1. why type changed
2. why key_len changed from 5 to 6
3. why rows in second query shows half of total number (800k)

And how can i make it faster without using `USE INDEX (index_users_on_category_id)`

Comment: Try to create index by `(deleted_at, category_id)`.

Comment: I added multi-column index, however it didn't help, it still use `index_users_on_deleted_at` as default one

Comment: As an experiment - replace ``SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, ... WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL`` with ``SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(`users`.`deleted_at`) AS count_all, ... WHERE 1``... and test it with above complex index and with `(category_id, deleted_at)` index.

Answer (score 0):

this index actually helped: `deleted_at, category_id`, however, I tried to do this without adding new index
Since there are much more records where deleted_at is null, i tried next queries:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count_all,
    `users`.`category_id` AS users_category_id
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
     `users`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `users`.`id` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY `users`.`category_id`;
```

And query optimizer used much better schema. I will try it soon on big set and hoe it will work.